# What is best way to design worker based back-end

Tags: database, web-services, api, backend

I want to design a backend which consists of many workers, database and an API. There are two ways for this in my mind.

First, there is a central API which contains database connection and models. It behaves as a database wrapper and it is Restful. All of workers, and other apps are connected to database with the central API.

[image]

Second, there is not a central API, and all of workers and other apps are connected to database directly.

[image]

Which is best way? First, second or none of these?

Comment: I think that more people will be able to answer your question there --> http://programmers.stackexchange.com. SO is mainly code-oriented and less conceptual. While programmers.stack is more about software architecture like your question seems to be about.

Comment: @Frederik.L this question is a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see [Green fields, blue skys, and the white board - what is too broad?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6961/31260) Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat Thanks for the reading. May I ask you why this question cannot fall into "data structure concepts" which is a valid topic according to these guidelines? I think that the criterias for a good candidate in Programmers.SE are too complex, hence not understood correctly from users refering from SO.